# Too much memory usage by Java in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

My laptop is having 2GB of RAM. So i installed Lubuntu as it is lightweight hoping my laptop would perform better. But java is using too much memory.

[image]

Is there any fix to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run JVM with args `-Xms{amount_of_memory}` and `-Xmx{amount_of_memory}`.

Where `Xms` is a minimal amount of memory that will be used upon start JVM and `Xmx` - max amount that can be reached by JVM

`M` and `G` can be used to specify Megabites or Gigabites respectively.

`java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M` - will start JVM with 1 Gb memory usage and allow to grow up to 2 Gb

Comment: i tried running that command java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M in terminal but nothing happend can you please tell me what exactly do i need to do

Comment: PS: I am new to lubuntu amd odnt know much about working with command line so please elaborate how to restrict java usage

Comment: Assume that you have high usage of RAM only when Android Studio is running. If it's so please read [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html) about VM settings in AS. Otherwise please provide a flow when you have high RAM usage.

PS: Java usually need a lot of resources, let's say it's a price for all the nice features that you get :)